# Best practice for updating a status field after a time interval in Supabase

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-database

I'm working on an application where I have a 'listings' table, and each listing has an 'expiration_date' and a 'status'. Once a payment is successful, the listing's expiration_date is set to 30 days in the future, and the status is set to 'active'.

However, I'm not quite sure about the best way to handle the status update once the listing has expired. After the expiration_date passes, I'd like to automatically update the status to 'expired'.

Did anyone do something similar to this in Supabase and what would be the best way to do it?

Should I run a cron job, or is there some built in functionality for this kind of cases?

Thanks!

Comment: You should run a cron job. You can use pg_cron in the instance of using it on Supabase itself.